# Difference between <body> and <g:layoutBody>

Tags: grails

may I know what's the difference between `<body>` and `<g:layoutBody>`, and how do I use these tags?

Comment: layoutBody - outputs the target pages body tag contents

Comment: So if I want to use body I'll have to include the layoutBody tags first?

Answer (score 0):

- **body** tag is a HTML tag. (nothing to do with grails)
- **g:layoutBody** should be used in templates to allow the concrete views to inject their data into the template.

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/layoutBody.html) on `g:layoutBody` is quite helpful.

In particular, this is their example of a decorator layout a.k.a. `main.gsp`. In this example `<g:layoutBody />` will be replaced with the body of the document to be decorated (e.g. `index.gsp`) and, of course, `<g:layoutHead />` will be replaced with the head of the document to be decorated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="global.js" />
    <g:layoutHead />
 </head>
 <body><g:layoutBody /></body>
</html>
```